# Python Cement Subcommands with Arguments

Tags: python

I'm using the Python cement framework and trying to create an app with several subcommands, each subcommand having its own arguments.

The [Diving Right In](http://cement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/quickstart/#diving-right-in) example shows how to make subcommands, but none of those have their own arguments.

The [Argument and Options Handling](http://cement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/arguments/) example shows how to handle arguments, but not with subcommands.

The [Application Controllers](http://cement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/controllers/) page again shows how to make subcommands, but no arguments specifically for a subcommand.

[Multiple Stacked Controllers](http://cement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/multiple_stacked_controllers/) came very close, but I find that I can't get it to look quite right. Here is what I have:

```
from cement.core.foundation import CementApp
from cement.core.controller import CementBaseController, expose


class MyBaseController(CementBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'base'
        description = "<Overall application description>"


class MySubcommand(CementBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'subcommand1'
        stacked_on = 'base'
        stacked_type = 'nested'
        description = '<Subcommand description>'
        arguments = [(['--bar'], {'help': 'An option visible only to subcommand1!'})]

    @expose(help='<Redundant subcommand description')
    def subcommand1(self):
        self.app.log.info("This is what happens when you run demo2.py subcommand1")


class MyApp(CementApp):
    class Meta:
        label = 'demo2'
        base_controller = 'base'
        handlers = [MyBaseController, MySubcommand]


with MyApp() as app:
    app.run()
```

This works, but the only problem is the awkwardly presented help text:

```
> python3 demo2.py subcommand1 --help
usage: demo2 (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}

<Subcommand description>

commands:

  subcommand1
    <Redundant subcommand description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --debug     toggle debug output
  --quiet     suppress all output
  --bar BAR   An option visible only to subcommand1!
```

As you can see, subcommand1 is presented as yet another subcommand to subcommand1, complete with redundant help text. Even if I omit the `expose` `help` argument, the confusing presentation stays.

If I use `stacked_type = 'embedded'` instead, then teach subcommand's arguments are visible to all other commands.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at using the new `ArgparseController` from the `argparse` extension (shipped with Cement).  It replaces `CementBaseController`, which will be going away completely in Cement 3.  The `ArgparseController` is much less customized, and stays out of the way more... so it is more of a direct use of Argparse (i.e. nested sub-commands/controllers are actually nested subparsers, with their own arguments, etc).

- http://builtoncement.com/2.10/whats_new.html#argparsecontroller
- http://builtoncement.com/2.10/api/ext/ext_argparse.html#cement-ext-ext-argparse

Cement 2 has not dropped `CementBaseController` or made `ArgparseController` the default to maintain compatibility, but it is available from the extension and is recommended to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example based on @derks answer. `ArgParseController` is apparently the new way to do things.

```
from cement.core.foundation import CementApp
from cement.ext.ext_argparse import ArgparseController, expose


class MyBaseController(ArgparseController):
    def default(self):
        self.app.args.print_help()

    @expose(
        arguments=[
            (['a'], {'help': 'A positional argument'}),
            (['--barg', '-b'], {'help': 'Keyword argument'}),
        ],
        help='<Subcommand description>')
    def subcommand(self):
        self.app.log.info("subcommand successful")


class MyApp(CementApp):
    class Meta:
        label = 'demo'
        handlers = [MyBaseController]


with MyApp() as app:
    app.run()
```

### Old answer

This is my original answer, basically a kludge using `CementBaseController`:

The `expose` [`hide` option](http://cement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/controller/#cement.core.controller.expose) can result in some pretty nice looking help text:

```
from cement.core.foundation import CementApp
from cement.core.controller import CementBaseController, expose


class MyBaseController(CementBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'base'
        description = "<Overall application description>"


class MySubcommand(CementBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'subcommand1'
        stacked_on = 'base'
        stacked_type = 'nested'
        description = '<Subcommand description>'
        arguments = [(['--bar'], {'help': 'An option visible only to subcommand1!'})]

    @expose(hide=True)
    def default(self):
        self.app.log.info("This is what happens when you run demo2.py subcommand1")


class MyApp(CementApp):
    class Meta:
        label = 'demo3'
        base_controller = 'base'
        handlers = [MyBaseController, MySubcommand]


with MyApp() as app:
    app.run()
```

Help text:

```
> python3 demo3.py subcommand1 --help
usage: demo3 (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}

<Subcommand description>

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --debug     toggle debug output
  --quiet     suppress all output
  --bar BAR   An option visible only to subcommand1!
```

Answer (score -2):

Is there a way display the help without --help for subcommand  ?

```
python3 demo3.py subcommand1
```

to display the same content of

```
python3 demo3.py subcommand1 --help
```

Comment: If you refer to an answer posted above, please leave a comment below it.

Comment: Before downvoting... understand the question.... I am asking here by default --help without specifying it